# ggplot2: Stacked bar labels displaying in incorrect position and order when categories are below zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a large set of diverging bar charts [(like those found here)](http://stephanieevergreen.com/?s=diverging%20bar%20charts) in R using ggplot2. However, I am having trouble getting the labels for undesirable categories (which are stacked below 0) to print in the right order and in the right locations. Here's some reproducable code:

```
foo <- data.frame(value=c(2:6)
                  ,percent=c(-.185, -.074, .148, .074, .518)
                  ,col=c("#EF8A62", "#FDDBC7", "#D1E5F0", "#67A9CF", "#2166AC")
                  ,set="Expectations")

semanticLevels <- c("Very Negative"
                    ,"Negative"
                    ,"Slightly Negative"
                    ,"Slightly Positive"
                    ,"Positive"
                    ,"Very Positive")

pal <- brewer.pal(6,"RdBu")

ggplot() + geom_bar(data=foo, aes(x = set, y=percent, fill=col), position="stack", stat="identity") +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("white")) +
  geom_text(data=foo, aes(x = set, y=percent, label=scales::percent(abs(percent))), position = position_stack(vjust = .5), angle=-90) +
  scale_fill_identity("", labels = semanticLevels, breaks=pal, guide=guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,1,.5), limits=c(-1,1),labels=scales::percent) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" )
```

This produces the following graph:

[Stacked (diverging) bar graph with misplaced data labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r52SL.png)

As you can see, all of the data labels for the desirable categories are centered in their appropriate categories, but for the undesirable categories below zero, the data labels are out of order and are not centered in their respective categories.

I have tried many solutions to this issue and have not come up with any simple changes that would address the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `ggplot` is messing up the stacking when you call each layer separately, but will work fine if you allow data and aesthetic to be inherited:

```
foo <- data.frame(value=c(2:6)
                  ,percent=c(-.185, -.074, .148, .074, .518)
                  ,col=c("#EF8A62", "#FDDBC7", "#D1E5F0", "#67A9CF", "#2166AC")
                  ,set="Expectations")

semanticLevels <- c("Very Negative"
                    ,"Negative"
                    ,"Slightly Negative"
                    ,"Slightly Positive"
                    ,"Positive"
                    ,"Very Positive")

pal <- brewer.pal(6,"RdBu")

ggplot(data=foo,aes(x = set, y=percent, fill=col)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("white")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(abs(percent))), position = position_stack(vjust = .5), angle=-90) +
  scale_fill_identity("", labels = semanticLevels, breaks=pal, guide=guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,1,.5), limits=c(-1,1),labels=scales::percent) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" )
```

[image: Done with inheritance]

If you want a more satisfying (and potentially more reliable) solution, you can specify positioning exactly yourself:

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- foo %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  mutate(position = ifelse(value<=3,sum(foo$percent[foo$value>value & foo$value<=3])
                           ,sum(foo$percent[foo$value<value & foo$value>3]))+.5*percent)

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=foo, aes(x = set, y=percent, fill=col), position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(data=foo, aes(x = set, y=position, label=scales::percent(abs(percent))), position = "identity", angle=-90) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("white")) +
  scale_fill_identity("", labels = semanticLevels, breaks=pal, guide=guide_legend(nrow=1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,1,.5), limits=c(-1,1),labels=scales::percent) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" )
```

[image: Done with explicit position]